# Why does sending **head to a function work while reversing an SLL and *head doesn't in C?

Tags: c

I am using Apple Clang 11.00 to compile my code to reverse a linked list. I was using this code at first but it didn't work:

```
void reverseSLL(node *head)
{
    node *cur, *next, *prev;

    cur = head;
    prev = next = NULL;

    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("SLL does not Exist.\n");
        return;
    }

    while (cur != NULL) {
        next =  cur->next;
        cur->next = prev;
        prev = cur;
        cur = next;
    }

    head = prev;
}
```

Then I switched to this and it worked:

```
void reverseSLL(node **head)
{
    node *cur, *next, *prev;

    cur = *head;
    prev = next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL) {
        printf("SLL does not Exist.\n");
        return;
    }

    while (cur != NULL) {
        next =  cur->next;
        cur->next = prev;
        prev = cur;
        cur = next;
    }

    *head = prev;
}
```

I don't understand why is this happening. Can anybody help?

Comment: C is pass by value. Always.

Comment: ... this `head = prev;` in fact does nothing, as it just changes the value of the **local** variable `head` and then exits.

Comment: Perhaps you might like to read up what the de-reference operator `*` does, how it works.

Comment: You could do it actually, if you properly copied the contents of one structure to the other.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments to functions in C are passed by value, which means that changes made to the value of the argument within the body of the function has no effect once the function returns. A simple example:

```
void foo(int a)
{
    a += 10;
}

int main()
{
    int b = 0;
    printf("before: %d\n", b);
    foo(b);
    printf("after: %d\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

This will print:

```
before: 0
after: 0
```

If you want the calling function (`main` in this case) to see the updated value, you have to pass a pointer to `int` (you could also return the updated value, but we'll ignore that here):

```
void foo(int *a)
{
    *a += 10;
}

int main()
{
    int b = 0;
    printf("before: %d\n", b);
    foo(&b); /* Note that we are taking the address of 'b' here */
    printf("after: %d\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

In this case our output would be:

```
before: 0
after: 10
```

Passing a pointer is no different. Making changes to the pointer in your function is not going to change it in the calling function so you have to pass a pointer to the pointer. This is why your second code example works.

Comment: I understand. But I am facing this problem only while reversing the SLL. Other functions (in my implementation) like inserting/deleting an element into/from the SLL work as intended just by sending `*head` instead of `**head` to the function.

Comment: Have you tried inserting a new element at the beginning of the list?

Comment: You're right. It is not working. So, the functions where the value of head updates don't work because I've called the function by value and not by reference. Thank You.

Comment: C doesn’t have references. You’ve passed something to a function and you want to modify that something so you need to pass a pointer to it instead. The “something” you are passing just happens to be a pointer.